# Which is more accepted or more common, “for some reason” or “for some reasons”?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I often hear native speakers say *for some reason*, but I think *reason* is usually a countable noun and "some reasons" can have the meaning of "an unspecified number of reasons". I think *for some reasons* ought to be a correct form of it.

What's your comment?

Is "for some reasons" used in everyday English? If it is, what's the difference between it and "for some reason"?

([The answer to the question that people think is a duplicate of mine](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5527/50) doesn't help, because it lists both singular and plural words used with "some".)

Comment: The phrase "for some reason" is saying "for this reason or that reason...", and only refers to a unique reason, so the singular *reason* is used. If there are multiple reasons, it has to be taken in context.

Comment: Do you mean "for some reasons" is wrong?

Comment: I don't think so. Is there also "For some reasons" in English?

Comment: It seems you don't accept “for some reasons”？

Answer (score 9):

> SOME (determiner)
>
> 1. of a certain unspecified number, amount, degree, etc:
>      "For *some* reason, I don't think this is grammatical."

Some is being used in the same sense as *unknown*. Being a *noun* starting with a vowel it is modified with the indefinite article *an*. So the meaning is "for an unknown reason."

In casual conversations you will commonly hear the redundant: "For some *unknown* reason."

Answer (score 7):

"For some reason" is the natural way to say "for one or more unknown reasons."

"For some reasons," like "for some one reason," are unlikely to be said because these phrases imply that the reasons are known.  Already noted in a comment:

> The phrase "for some reason" is saying "for this reason or that reason...", and only refers to a unique reason, so the singular reason is used. If there are multiple reasons, it has to be taken in context. -- user3169