# "some . . . vote" or "some . . . votes"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

The following sentence is from [NBCnews](http://www.nbcnews.com/meet-the-press/clinton-lead-over-trump-would-grow-without-sanders-race-n581961).

> He could also win some of the Sanders vote.

Is "vote" mentioned here correct? I think "vote" should be in plural form.

If singular "vote" is correct then what does it mean here? Does its meaning change if the noun is changed to singular or plural?

Note: I went through [ell.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5525/singular-or-plural-after-some) question regarding the usage of "some" but I feel it is not the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you should look into "Vote" not "Some".
(the vote) - the choice expressed collectively by a body of electors or by a specified group:

> - The decision will be put by referendum to the vote of electors in the different regions.
> - He could also win some of the Sanders vote.

For more info, refer [this.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vote)

Answer (score 1):

One of the meanings of the noun ["vote"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vote) is "the total number of votes cast in an election", and it is this how the word is used in your example, therefore - *some* of the Sanders vote.